# SQL Replication Errors: Replication 'publish' already been set to true and logreader agent already exists

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error when trying to create replication:

> The replication option 'publish' of database 'servername' has already
>   been set to true. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 14035)  The logreader agent already exists. Use 'sp_changelogreader_agent' to
>   change any settings/properties. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 21831).  NOTE:
>   The step was retried the requested number of times (5) without
>   succeeding.  The step failed.

I used the wizard to generate the script, then I use the scripts in job steps.  I deleted the existing replicaiton and then reran the job that creates both the snapshot and the transaction replication and it gives me the same error.

I'm not sure if you need any more information, if so, just let me know.  Currently, I'm not sure what else to look into?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What did you do to "deleted the existing replicaiton"? It looks it wasn't enough.  Knowing how to completely remove and recreate a replication topology is required to support a production deployment.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/disable-publishing-and-distribution?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, thanks for your reply.  I used SSMS and right-clicked the local publications that needed to be removed and then selected delete.

Comment: If you only deleted the publications, then you only need to recreate the publications.   The database is still enabled for publication and ready to add publications.